# When to Use Await Keywork in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm currently trying to learn asyncio in Python. I know that the await keyword tells the loop that it can switch coroutines. However, when should I actually use it? Why not put it before everything?

Additionally, why is the await before 'response.text()', why not before the session.get(url)?

```
async def print_preview(url):
    # connect to the server
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # create get request
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            # wait for response
            response = await response.text()

            # print first 3 not empty lines
            count = 0
            lines = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, response.split('\n')))
            print('-'*80)
            for line in lines[:3]:
                print(line)
            print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `await` with functions that are marked as *coroutine* in the documentation. For example, [`ClientResponse.text`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.text) is marked as coroutine, while [`ClientResponse.close`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.close) is not, which means you must await the former and must not await the latter. If you forget to await a coroutine, it simply won't execute and its return value will be a "coroutine object", which is useless (except for use with `await`).

`session.get()` returns an [async context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with). When passed to `async with`, the coroutines it implements are awaited behind the scenes.

Also note that awaiting is not the only thing you can do with coroutines, the other is converting them into tasks, which allows them to run in parallel (without additional cost on the OS level). For more information, consult a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) on asyncio.